# Access error occured in Ruby 1.9 + MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows, ruby

I can't connect mysql db with ruby1.9

- OS -> Windows XP SP2
- Ruby -> 1.9.1p0
- dbi -> 0.4.2
- dbd-mysql -> 0.4.3
- MySQL API module for Ruby -> 2.7.3
- DB(MySQL) -> 5.1.34-community

**Because msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found, I was not able to start this application.**

What's wrong

Answer (score 0):

One of the gems is looking for ruby 1.8.x probably the dbi or dbd gem.  Try it with ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the newer Ruby installer built with mingw. A tutorial on installing Ruby 1.9.1 with MySQL is available from [The Ruby Installer Tutorials](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

One of the modules your application depends on was built for Ruby 1.8. The most likely culprit is the MySQL client binding, but it could be some other dependency being imported elsewhere in the code, as well.

Generally speaking, the support for Ruby 1.9 isn't yet all that good across most applications and 3rd-party libraries. Unless you have a very strong reason to use it, you'll probably have better luck sticking with the latest 1.8.X release.